# jhipster DTO generation: can I have a relation to non-DTO-Entity?

Tags: java, jhipster, mapstruct

The default in Jhipster is not to use DTOs, but use the directly.
So my first entity `company` does not uses a DTO.
Now I have generated an entity `tour` with a many-to-one relationship to company, and with service layer and DTO-support.

During generation, I get the following message:

```
WARNING! This entity has the DTO option, 
and it has a relationship with entity "company" that doesn't have the DTO option. 
This will result in an error.
```

When I compile the resulting project, I get an error, like promised:

```
java:11: error: cannot find symbol
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, CompanyMapper.class})
```

I tried to remove the CompanyMapper.class in the Annotation, then I get the error in the following lines:

```
@Mapping(source = "companyId", target = "company")
Tour toEntity(TourDTO tourDTO);

 Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property "java.lang.Long companyId" to java.lang.Object: de....Tour fromId(java.lang.Long id), de...User de.....mapper.UserMapper.userFromId(java.lang.Long id).
```

Do I need to build a company DTO, or is there another way that I can tell mapstruct to access the company ?

Comment: In my opinion, DTOs should be the default option in JHipster as it's really wrong to expose your JPA entities in your REST API. Any reason why you don't want to add the DTO option to your existing entity?

Comment: Without DTO and without service it is simplier, in this use case the "company" is just bunch of data fields. So I like that there are no extra classes to write and manage. The Tour, on the other side, will get more logic, and probably even get different DTOs for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed the Mapper with the following:

First I removed the "CompanyMapper.class" from the `@Mapper` Annotation, like I described in the question.

The I added a method to the mapper to create a company from an id. If I understand it correctly, this enables the mapper to call "`tour.setCompany()`" when creating a Tour-object and there is an `companyId` in the `TourDTO`.

```
 default Company companyFromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Company obj = new Company();
        obj.setId(id);
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: This is a completely OK solution to the problem. I have additionally added another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529530/1115491) which shows an alternative way of achieving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The initially proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525084/1115491) is one way to solve the issue.

Another way, not sure if it is even required and desired, would be to directly fetch the `Company` from the database (you then get managed entity).

If you have a `CompanyRepository` with a method `findById(Long)` then you can do.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, 
CompanyRepository.class})
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "companyId", target = "company")
    Tour toEntity(TourDTO tourDTO);
}
```

This is in more detailed explained in [Invoking other mappers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers)